# REXX /CLIST PANEL- finding code location

Tags: panel, rexx, clist

Is there any way to find quickly the program behind a rexx/clist panel.
I know that i have check one by one all the panle librairies to find the panel.
But it takes lot of time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First step is is to turn **panelid** on with the ispf panelid command

```
panelid on
```

This will list name of panel on all ISPF panels being displayed

---

Actually you do not need to search each panel library, you can use Ispf **rexx** program
to allocate a **DataId** to **ispplib** and **edit** using the **DataId** i.e.

```
/* rexx */
address ispexec
'LMINIT DATAID(didVar) DDNAME(ISPPLIB)'
'edit DATAID('didVar') memeber(panelname)'
'lmfree DATAID('didVar')'
```

**Note:** If you make changes while editing, the changes are saved in the first library in the list. So if ISPPLIB is setup as

```
  my.panels
  test.panels
  prod.panels
```

any changes will always be save in my.panels

**Note:** if you **edit** without a specifying the **member**, the member list will include a dataset number relating to the top level where the panel will be picked up from.

**Note:** There is almost certainly a limit on the number datasets that can be accessed this way. So if there are a lot of datasets allocated to ISPPLIB, there could be issues.

---

Hopefully there will be a

1. Relationship between where the panel is stored and where the rexx/clist is stored
2. relationship between the panel name and the rexx/clist name; often they are nearly the same. Some times the panel might have a **P** at a certain character position while the rexx might have a **R**

If there is no relationship between the panel and the Rexx/clist; you will have to search for it. You could set up a batch search for to search for the panel in all the rexx/clist libraries. A bit of a pain to set up, but it only has to be done **once** and then you have it for future use.
If you want to get really smart you could use the LM services to extract rexx/clist libraries

Comment: Thanks a lot Bruce ,It was great help!  i used 'browse DATAID('didVar') memeber(panelname)' rather edit as intetion was just to see the code.

Answer (score 0):

Building on some of what @Bruce Martin said, type `TSO ISRDDN` on any `COMMAND ==>` line in ISPF.  Use the `member` command to search your SYSPROC and SYSEXEC concatenations.  You can also use `SRCHFOR` when in a member list, looking for the panel name.